# swfobject.embedSWF showing black screen in Firefox randomly with multiple flash object/screens

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, flash, swfobject

I need to show multiple video(9-12 screens) in single window. For that I am generating flash object with following script :

```
        strHtml += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        strHtml += "var flashvars = {}; ";
        strHtml += "var params = {}; ";
        strHtml += "params.allowfullscreen = \"true\"; ";
        strHtml += "params.menu = \"false\"; ";
        strHtml += "params.wmode = \"transparent\"; ";
        strHtml += "var attributes = {}; ";
        strHtml += "flashvars.pmode = \"live\"; ";
        strHtml += "flashvars.url  = \"" + URL + "\"; ";
        strHtml += "flashvars.thumb = \"Images/full.png\";";
        strHtml += "swfobject.embedSWF(\"../../Flash/wink_player_traffic.swf\", \"container\", \"" + width + "\", \"" + height + "\", \"9.0.115\", \"../../Flash/expressInstall.swf\", flashvars, params, attributes);<\/script>";
        strHtml += "<div id=\"container"\">";
        strHtml += "<a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer\" ><img style=\"height:100%;width:100%\" src=\"../../Images/no_flash_640.jpg\" alt=\"Get Flash Player\" /></a>";
        strHtml += "</div>";
        $('#Container12').html(strHtml);
```

Sometime some video showing black screen and some video are working. after resizing, black screen videos are working fine. we are using SWFObject v2.3.20130521

Comment: Any browser has a limit on concurrent HTTP requests (definitely to the same address, probably to the same server, maybe at all) per page, like 10 or so, I tested in in 2009 and results were slightly different for different browsers, so it's not impossible that these videos are getting downloaded simultaneously and the page hits its limit.